# Low validation accuracy after InceptionResNetV2 model transfer learning

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, image-processing, keras, computer-vision

I need a Tensorflow model to classify images into 4 distinct categories for which I am doing transfer learning on pretrained InceptionResNetV2 model(weights='Imagenet'). During model.fit() I get an accuracy of 97.4% with loss of 0.3 while my validation accuracy remains stuck at 84% with a loss of 0.4. Am I overfitting, How do I improve my validation accuracy?

```
base_model = InceptionResNetV2(input_shape=(299,299,3),weights='imagenet', include_top=False)


x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = Dense(2048,activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.03)(x)
x = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.05)(x)
x = Dense(1024,activation='relu')(x)
x = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.05)(x)
x = Dense(128,activation='relu')(x)

predictions = Dense(4, activation='softmax')(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding data augmentation to your code; that'll fix the overfitting issue. Something like the code below:

```
data_augmentation = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomRotation(0.01),
    tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomContrast(0.25),
    tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomTranslation(height_factor = (-0.1, 0.1), width_factor = (-0.1, 0.1))])

inp = tf.keras.Input(shape=IMG_SIZE)
x = data_augmentation(inp)
x = base_model(x, training=False)
```